# Does simply grinding malt make diastatic malt powder?

Tags: baking, bread, bagels, malt

I am looking to make some bagels. I already have malt powder which I believe to be nondiastatic but I am also interested in adding diastatic malt powder, which I'm having a hard time finding.

I have some pilsner malt on hand. Can I simply grind this malt to make diastatic malt powder? I have a powerful food processor and blender and I reckon I can make a powder of it.

Answer (score 1):

Revision to original answer, I hadn't thought of this. No, you probably can't use beer-ready malt.
*From comments…*
*Isn't malt already germinated though? Isn't that the whole point?*
The trouble with malt ready to make beer is that it's killed a fair amount of the enzyme in the drying process. Malt for beer is dried at around 70°C [pilsner apparently hotter than other types]. Diastatic malt is dried at no more than 55°C [one source said they use 40° to be safe] to not kill the enzyme.

You can make your own if you can sprout then dry 'green' barley grains before grinding.

The diastase comes from the sprouting process.

I found some DIY instructions, for if you're very keen. [Making your own diastatic malt](https://www.weekendbakery.com/posts/making-your-own-diastatic-malt/) The whole process would take about a week, if it doesn't go mouldy as you're sprouting & you don't kill the enzymes by drying too hot.
I'm not sure it's something I'd like to tackle myself.

I found this - [Unraveling the Malt Puzzle: Michigan Brewers Guild MBAA – District Michigan Winter Conference Joseph Hertrich January 13, 2012](https://fliphtml5.com/qaug/ideq/basic) which, amongst many other things, talks about trying to achieve balance between diastatic power & [everything else]. I have to admit my eyes glazed over for a lot of it; the bit relevant is towards the end.

I guess after this later discovery, the best I could say is "Try it & see".

Comment: Isn't malt already germinated though? Isn't that the whole point?

Comment: Ahh… minor detail ;)) Adding to answer...

Comment: This does seem a bit... overkill for bagels.

Comment: @Marti - especially when Amazon will deliver the correct stuff to my door by tomorrow.

Comment: @Marti not everyone in the world has access to Amazon USA supplies.

Comment: What confuses me is that the malt itself has relatively high diastatic power which presumably means in a powdered form it would be....diastatic malt powder?

Comment: @Behacad: I wasn't the one who suggested Amazon.